# best way to break up fixed width files in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, fixed-width

Below is the sample data.

```
 string1 <- c(320100000020220311020210)
 string2 <- c(320100000020220312120211)

 testitem <- data.frame (string1,string2)
```

My first question is what is the best method to break up the strings in a specified fashion. For example, the breaks should appear after characters 2,4,10,14,16,18,19, and 23. In this case, the end result should appear as such

```
 32    01    0000000    2022    03    11    0   2021    0
```

Comment: `substring` is vectorized, you could also use that `x <- c(2, 4, 10, 14, 16, 18, 19, 23); substring(string1, c(1, x + 1), c(x, nchar(string1)))` and you can vectorize it again: `Vectorize(substring, 'text')(c(string1, string2), c(1, x + 1), c(x, nchar(string1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are character strings, then use `read.fwf` from `base R`

```
read.fwf(textConnection(unlist(testitem)),
    widths = c(2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1), colClasses = "character")
```

-output

```
  V1 V2     V3   V4 V5 V6 V7   V8 V9
1 32 01 000000 2022 03 11  0 2021  0
2 32 01 000000 2022 03 12  1 2021  1
```

---

Or another option is `separate`

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(col1 = unlist(testitem)) %>% 
  separate(col1, into = str_c("V", 1:9), sep = c(2, 4, 10, 14, 16, 18, 19, 23))
# A tibble: 2 × 9
  V1    V2    V3     V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 32    01    000000 2022  03    11    0     2021  0    
2 32    01    000000 2022  03    12    1     2021  1
```

#### data

```
string1 <- c("320100000020220311020210")
string2 <- c("320100000020220312120211")
testitem <- data.frame (string1,string2)
```

Comment: maybe should start another question but if I need to collapse a data string from 32xyzabc      3201 into 32xyzabc3201.. what is the best method. I thought that my data strings did not have spaces but come to find out that they do.

Comment: @TimWilcox you can just use `paste0` i.e. `paste0(out$..`

Comment: @TimWilcox Sorry was a bit busy, you can do `tibble(col1 = unlist(testitem)) %>% 
  separate(col1, into = str_c("V", 1:9), sep = c(2, 4, 10, 14, 16, 18, 19, 23)) %>% mutate(V1 = str_c(V1, "xyzabc3201"))`